# Amazon SNS Sending direct push notification to individual device

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am developing REST API application on Symfony3. I want to register mobile devices and send direct push notifications to them. For example, when one user sends feedback to another, that second user will get push notification.

With Amazon SNS is it possible not to broadcast, but directly notify individual device from server?

Answer (score 1):

yes, is possible, you create a platform and then you can create multiple 'Endpoints' wich represent a devices in SNS with the corresponding token or device id. then you can notify to one device using the endpoint arn value